# IE 11 not breaking long words

Tags: html, css

There are two divs. The left one has specified it's css like this:

```
max-width:30%;
min-width:450px;
```

The right one has a

```
flex-grow:1
```

There is a lot of other styling but Im hopefully just pointing out the most relevant.

Inside the right div there are a few elements. 
The innerst element is a p-tag where I have tried to put all possible directives to make it break long words.
The last attempt is this:

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

I also tried to combine with other directives, like

```
max-width:100%
width:100%
display: block (but even all other possible values)
```

Many people seem to have solved this using microsoft specific word-break/wrap. In my case it doesn't succeed.
When having a word composed by for example 50 characters (without white space) a big part of the word is not visible as it goes outside the browser.
The page itself doesn't have an horizontal scroll (there is maybe other styling that stops this).

Even adding

```
overflow:hidden/scroll
```

inside the p-tag didn't help. I see the horizontal scroll but it doesn't really let you scroll to the right, even if the scrollbar is there.
This is crazy situation. Debugging with explorer devtools is not the best experience.
Anyone that can help?

Comment: move the <p> tag inside a <div> (which is dynamic and relative) and set overflow: auto; to this div.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Not easy to create a runnable example. However, the scroll never works. No matter what I do. Replaced p-tag with div. The only thing that could be close to working solution is: max-width:60%;display:inline-flex; However, for big screens it looks a little weird with container that is filled almost half space.